# Opera Mini Servers

Tags: mobile, network-protocols, tcp, opera-mini

Is it possible to use Opera Mini Servers for my own mobile app (the way Opera Mini uses them)? To do that, knowledge of their server protocol is needed, as far as i can understand. Maybe, there are some libs developed already...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opera uses OBML as opposed to HTML which stands for Opera Binary Markup Language. It's a proprietary protocol and a few years ago I couldn't find any reasonable documentaion enough to start developing a custom client. You can try to start from here http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-binary-markup-language/

You could also try to decompile their Mini browser written in Java to understand it more.